# How to include a declaration in the comma operator?

Tags: c++, operators, declaration

I have two simple testing lines:

```
cout<<(cout<<"ok"<<endl, 8)<<endl;

cout<<(int i(8), 8)<<endl;
```

The first line worked, but the second failed compilation with

```
error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
```

For some reason, I do need a declaration in the comma operator. To be more specific, I want to declare some variables, obtain their values, and assign them to my constant class members from the initialization list of my class constructor. Following shows my intentions. If not achievable using comma operator, any another suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void readFile(const string & fileName, int & a, int & b)
{
    fstream fin(fileName.c_str());
    if (!fin.good()) {cerr<<"file not found!"<<endl; exit(1);}
    string line;
    getline(fin, line);
    stringstream ss(line);
    try {ss>>a>>b;}
    catch (...) {cerr<<"the first two entries in file "<<fileName<<" have to be numbers!"<<endl; exit(1);}
    fin.close();
}

class A
{
    private:
        const int _a; 
        const int _b; 
    public:
        A(const string & fileName)
            :   
            _a((int a, int b, readFile(fileName,a,b), a)),
            _b((int a, int b, readFile(fileName,a,b), b)) 
        {   
            /*  
            int a, b;
            readFile(fileName,a,b);
            _a = a;_b = b;
            */
        }   

        void show(){cout<<_a<<" "<<_b<<endl;}
};

int main()
{
    A a("a.txt");
    a.show();
}
```

Comment: please, don't..

Comment: "I do need a declaration in the comma operation" - no you don't. And quite fortunately, you can't either. You do need to re-think your design decisions, though.

Comment: perhaps change the title to: how to write invalid C++?

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem. Could you tell us the reason behind the mysterious "For some reason?"

Comment: Put the behavior in a separate function, initialize your member from the function's return value.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Too bad I've run out of comment votes for today.

Comment: @H2CO3, You can have mine.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight All functional languages have an extremely useful `let` expression which allows local name binding. For example, with a combination of `let` and C++ reference types, you could implement `x += y` as sugar for `let lhs = x in lhs = lhs + y`, preserving the behaviour that `x` is only evaluated once.

Comment: @JonPurdy I'm sure C++ is not generally regarded as a functional language.

Comment: @H2CO3 Sure, I was just giving an example of how this kind of thing can be useful. sehe’s answer with lambdas is actually the standard trick for desugaring `let`, barring some type system details.

Comment: You realizae you're going to read the file twice here, yes?

Comment: You are at the very least abusing the comma operator here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot.  This is unpossible in C++.  The fact that you are trying to do this is also a code smell.  Something's not right here.

> I want to declare some variables, obtain their values, and assign them
>   to my constant class members from the initialization list of my class
>   constructor. Not sure how to achieve this.

You didn't say what you intended to do with these variables you declare after you've used the values, but I'm guessing that once you've finished with the values, you've finished with the variables.  In other words, they are temporary.

Your edited example suggests that my assumption is correct.  It also confirms the code smell.  Based on your (intended) code, you are going to read the file twice.

I'd say the most straightforward way to do this is to use an intermediary, kind of like a factory class.  This also has the benefit of being able to read the file only once, as opposed to twice as you are doing now.

```
void readFile (const std::string& fileName, int& a, int& b)
{
    // some magic
    a = 42;
    b = 314;
}

class FileReader
{
public:
    FileReader (const std::string fileName)
    :
        mFileName (fileName),
        mA (42),
        mB (314)
    {
        // something happens like reading the file
    }

    int GetA () const
    {
        return mA;
    }
    int GetB () const
    {
        return mB;
    }
private:
    int mA;
    int mB;
    std::string mFileName;
};

class A
{
private:
    const int mA;
    const int mB;
public:
    A (const FileReader& reader)
    :
        mA (reader.GetA()),
        mB (reader.GetB())
    {
    }
};
```

Using this `FileReader` is simple:

```
int main()
{
    A myA (FileReader ("somefile.txt"));
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I should have stated my intention at the very beginning and will direct to the right solution much sooner. The third-party class promptly fetches the values that are immediately ready to be consumed by user class. Cool!

Answer (score 6):

Declarations are *statements* and not *expressions*.  You cannot place statements inside of expressions, though you can place expressions inside of statements.  Accordingly, you cannot declare a variable in the way that you're describing above.  You'll need to separate it out into multiple different statements.

I would be surprised if if you actually *needed* to do this.  If you do, there is probably something problematic about your design.

Hope this helps!

Comment: A declaration is not always a statement - only if it appears within a compound-statement.

Comment: + I think OP also need an explanation for message *`expected primary-expression before 'int'`* , he might expecting something else

Answer (score 5):

A lambda allows a declaration within an expression.  So this is possible:

```
std::cout << ([]{ int i(8); m_i = i; }(), 8) << std::endl;
```

But it's really weird - I assume this will be in some `#define` macro that makes it appear closer to normal.

Comment: Where does that `m_i` come from?

Comment: @jrok: I made it up, because I wanted the example lambda to at least have some side effect.

Answer (score 5):

You should have a look at Boost Phoenix (which has phoenix::let to do roughly this). Bear in mind, Phoenix is an eDSL, really (embedded domain specific language).

You could do an ugly trick and abuse lambdas:

```
cout<< ([]->int{ int i(8); return 8; })() <<endl;
```

Comment: Wawo!!, where from you bring this? nice trick, belongs to new version of c++?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, yes, lambdas (the code sample, not Boost) are C++11.

Comment: By C++11 rules the lambda's return type is `void`, isn't it?

Comment: Not so much an abuse; at least it’s way better than the GNU `({ ... })` extension.

Comment: @H2CO3 give me a link instead, I am an ancient programmer :)

Comment: @aschepler, Yes, until C++14 I think.

Comment: It's only inferred if there's nothing but `return` statement in the body.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan [Here you are.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/spirit/phoenix/doc/html/index.html)

Comment: @jrok, I believe putting in something like a `static_assert` with it will still work, won't it?

Comment: @chris `static_assert` is a declaration, not a statement, so maybe. I'm not sure.

Comment: @jrok, After looking, I don't think it can. I do think it can be used in `constexpr` functions, though.

Comment: @chris It's a defect, anyway, see 975. [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html).

Comment: @jrok, I could have sworn it changed for C++14, what with the normal functions getting special treatment. Let me check. Edit: I'd say looks like it: *The
lambda return type is auto, which is replaced by the trailing-return-type if provided and/or deduced from
return statements as described in 7.1.6.4.*

Comment: @chris That's what I'm saying, it's a defect in C++11 and will be fixed in C++14.

Comment: @jrok, Oh, forgive my ignorance.

Comment: @H2CO3, sehe: Can you write similar funny code in `C` for me?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Yes. Using GCC extensions: The **['Expression Statement' extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs)** allows you to write e.g. `({ int y = foo (); int z;
        if (y > 0) z = y;
        else z = - y;
        z; })` which is just an expression returning `abs(foo())`

Comment: @sehe Very nice, I will learn this. Thanks Sehe! very interesting.